Why is implicitly-generated constructor different from user-provided one?
Given the following code (available on godbolt):
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

class A {
  public:
    A() : top_(data_) {}
  private:
    // Note: removing alignas removes the `rep stosq` from gcc output
    alignas(std::max_align_t) std::byte data_[1024];
    std::byte* top_;
};

class B {
public:
    B() {};
    void f();
private:
    A a;
};

class C {
public:
    C() = default;
    void f();
private:
    A a;
};

void f() {
    B b{}; // using B b = B() or B b; does not change the output
    b.f();
}

void g() {
   C c{}; // C c = C() does not change the output, C c; does
   c.f();
}

The two functions compile into the following (with clang, see godbolt for other compilers, all generating a rep stos instruction in place of the memset):
f():
        sub     rsp, 1032
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 4]
        call    B::f()@PLT
        add     rsp, 1032
        ret

g():
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 1040
        lea     rbx, [rsp + 12]
        mov     edx, 1028
        mov     rdi, rbx
        xor     esi, esi
        call    memset@PLT
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    C::f()@PLT
        add     rsp, 1040
        pop     rbx
        ret

In my case, A is a stack allocator, so memset-ing at creation is quite wasteful. This happens on GCC, Clang, and MSVC, so there must be some standard clause I'm missing. Even substituting data_ with a union doesn't change that.
Why are B and C initialized differently? cppreference says:

... and it [the implicitly-generated constructor] has the same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list.

It further states that

class types with an empty user-provided constructor may get treated differently than those with an implicitly-defined default constructor during value initialization

Though that is somewhat ambiguous, I thought it might refer to the fact that user-provided constructors make the class no longer trivially constructible.
Could someone provide clarification into this please?

Yes, in godbolt it's clear from the assembly. I'll edit the question to include that. Will edit the manually defined thing to be more precise as well.

This depends on 1. how you create the object, e.g. in which scope and whether you use C c;, C c{}; or C c = C(); (all with different semantics) and in the case of C c{}; also on the C++ version. So please show how you are creating the objects. But, importantly, in no case does the constructor initialize data_. If at all, it is the initialization syntax that causes data_ to be initialized to zero.

@user17732522 In the godbolt demo they've shown how they create the instance. But they should also post it here on SO. They use C c{};

Yeah, sorry for not including that, it's quite big and thought will be easier to provide as  a link. Changing C c{} to C c = C() does not change the assembly. Doing just C c; of course does but then potential other fields would be left uninitialized as well.

"Doing just C c; of course does but then potential other fields would be left uninitialized as well.": No, that's initializing with the default constructor as you want. Syntax with empty braces and parentheses initializes (potentially) more than what your constructors intend to initialize. You should use B b;/C c; if it is important to you that nothing is additionally zero-initialized.

@ARentalTV My answer was non-sense. Sorry, I didn't have my morning coffee yet. I will rewrite it later.

@user17732522 I've added the explanation for the observed behavior. Basically, this is due to value initialization and mainly due to the fact the B::B() is user-provided while C::C()=default is not.

tldr; B's ctor is user-provided because it is not defaulted on its first declaration while C's ctor is not user-provided. This results in object c being first zero initialized which is why we see some extra assembly code for c as explained below.

The behavior of the program can be understood using dcl.init.
First note that both B b{}; and C c{}; are list-initialization which has the following effect:


List-initialization of an object or reference of type cv T is defined as follows:


3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5 Otherwise, Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.


Which means both the objects will be value initialized. So we move onto value-initialization:

To value-initialize an object of type T means:

If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), then let C be the constructor selected to default-initialize the object, if any.
If C is not user-provided, the object is first zero-initialized.
In all cases, the object is then default-initialized.


Note the emphasis on user-provided. In particular, from dcl.fct.def.defaut we see that only the ctor B::B() is user-provided because it is not default in its first declaration.

A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.

Thus the ctor C::C()=default is not user-provided and the object c will first be zero-initialized as opposed to the object b. The object b will not be zero initialized.

As discussed in the comments under the question, this is importantly different before C++20, where C was an aggregate, so that it would only value-initialize the a subobject, which in turn means no zero-initialization of data_.

@user17732522 Yeah, I did see that so I picked up the C++26's working draft to answer for the latest case.
